# how to send all images in folder to clinet using tcp server client?

Tags: android, image, delphi, tcp, indy

how to send multiple images from a specific folder from client to server. I managed to send only one image!
i used this code

client code

```
fn := 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\11/65474.jpg';
fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead);
Host := Edit1.Text;
idTCPClient1.Connect;
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(fs);
```

Server Code

```
procedure TForm3.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  fs: TFileStream;       
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\pic\.png', fmCreate);   
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(fs, -1, True);
end;
```

the idea is to send all imges in folder to a client from one tcpserver.idTCPCLient plz help??
im sorry for noob question.

Comment: why the android tag?

Comment: strange file paths: `...\11/...` and `\.png`

Comment: android tag because im working on android app

Comment: the path is ok. i still can receive the pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls to `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` are mismatched.

By default, `ReadStream()` expects the stream size to be sent before the stream data. When `AByteCount` is -1 and `AReadUntilDisconnect` is False (the default parameter values), `ReadStream()` reads the first 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the `TIdIOHandler.LargeStream` property) to know how many bytes to read into the `TStream`.  However, you are setting `AReadUntilDisconnect` to True instead, so `AByteCount` is ignored, and `ReadStream()` will not exit until the client disconnects from the server.  That is the wrong functionality to use if you need to receive more than one stream (or anything else after the first stream, for that matter).

By default, the `AWriteByteCount` parameter of `Write(TStream)` is False, so it does not send the stream size.  When `AWriteByteCount` is set to True instead, `Write()` sends the stream size using 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the `TIdIOHandler.LargeStream` property) before then sending the stream content.

So, you are telling the client NOT to send the stream size, and telling the server to IGNORE the stream size (OK for the example you showed, but not OK for your intended goal), but you are also telling the server to WAIT until the client disconnects to signal the end of the stream, but the client is not disconnecting after sending the stream.

Try something more like this instead:

```
idTCPClient1.Host := Edit1.Text;
idTCPClient1.Connect;
...

for fn in TDirectory.GetFiles('C:/1/') do
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(ExtractFileName(fn));
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(fs, 0, True);
  end;
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
...
idTCPClient1.Disconnect;
```

```
procedure TForm3.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  fn: string;
  fs: TFileStream;       
begin
  fn := 'some base path\' + ExtractFileName(AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn);
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmCreate);
  try
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(fs, -1, False);
    finally
      fs.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile(fn);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, there is a very bare bones protocol.  A more flexible protocol would use a command/response model so a client can send different types of commands other than file transfers, a client can ask permission to send a file before actually sending it, the server can send a  confirmation if a file was successfully received or not, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, but in the client code i didnt understand the loop part, i wanna to send all folder contents as fast as possible to the server(PC), where fn := 'C:/1/*.*'; ?? . sorry i left delphi programming year ago :(

Comment: You have to search through the source folder looking for files you are interested in sending, such as with [`System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles).

Comment: yes i know how to use TDirectory.GetFiles() and list all pics from a folder in a list box then send all pics , that is my methodology, but for the loop..ListBox1.Items[i] ??? .. to send all items from the listbox.. i hope you didnt lost me ?

Comment: So what's the problem? I assume you do know how to loop through a list/array, right?

Comment: yes right ??, that is the main problem, the damn loop

Comment: `TStrings` has `Count` and `Strings[]` properties, eg: `for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do begin fn := ListBox1.Items[I]; ... end`. Or use a newer `for..in` loop instead: `for fn in ListBox1.Items do`.

Comment: super,i get it all, your the real MVP bro, Many thanks